# How to submit form data to php sql database from chrome extension

Tags: php, javascript, forms, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I don't know whats wrong with this code but it is not working. I changed form method to post and get but nothing worked. I want to submit this form to DB.

`popup.html:`

```
<form id='myForm' action='savenewfeed.php' method="get">
        URL:
        <input class= 'vals' type="text" name="feed" id="url">
        <br>
        Title : 
        <input class= 'vals' type="text" name="title" id="title">
        <br>
        Channel:
        <select class= 'vals' name='pid'>
          <option value="2">Big</option>
          <option value="3">H</option>
          <option value="4">T</option>
        </select>

        <button id='sbmt'>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

`manifest:`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "One-click Kittens",
  "description": "This extension gets current url of browser",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
   "tabs",
"cookies",
"http://*/*",
"http://*/",
"https://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
    }
```

popup.js:

```
function myAlert(){
document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
document.getElementById('sbmt').addEventListener('click', myAlert);
});
```

when i click the button, my php code appears in chrome extension, whereas , that php code to submit data works perfectly in simple web app.

Comment: If you can see your php code in your chrome extension. there is definitely something wrong with your web server . because web servers should never output the php source code directly. give us more information about your webserver

Comment: webserver is running fine, even that php file is also working fine when try to use with html page submit, or when access directly

Comment: my localhost is http://localhost:8080/ . Is it ok or extension is not accepting 8080?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change form action to absolute url of your submit script. don't use relative path. for example

```
<form id='myForm' action='http://localhost.com/mydir/savenewfeed.php' method="get">
```

Comment: give example form tag plz

Comment: @Satpal this *is* the answer to the question

Comment: @TheRaaaZ in addition, you don't have to include your php file in your extension. Your php file should stay exclusively on your server.

Comment: @rsanchez, I made the comment on his first version, I am glad he updated answer

Comment: i already tried this, but it not create any error or response. Just silent!